# Logging in to chat is so very, very hard!

Tags: support, chat

This might be a duplicate. I can see that people have had this problem in the past.

Logging into chat is hit or miss for me, and it's almost always miss. My (in)ability to log into chat makes a major league baseball pitcher's batting average look absolutely phenomenal.

Where things fail:

- On one of the many SE network sites where I am active, some discussion makes me think there's something in chat that's applicable.
- The site doesn't have a nice sidebar that says "come here to chat!"
- So I go to chat.stackexchange.com and find the relevant chat site.
- And I'm not logged in. Instead I see "You must be logged in to talk. See the faq for more information."

Both "logged in" and "faq" are hyperlinks. Clicking on "faq" says I need to be logged in to chat. (Duh.) Clicking on "logged in" brings me to a nice page that has a nice notification bar

> Welcome to The Stack Exchange Network chat! You'll need 20 reputation to talk here. This site is moderated by the community, so please be respectful of your fellow The Stack Exchange Network users. And while you're at it, check out the FAQ!
>
> Please log in to any StackExchange site first, or log in via StackExchange.com.

I have a bit more than 20 reputation points on the SE network, so that's not the problem. Here, both "FAQ" and "log in via StackExchange.com" are hyperlinks. The FAQ once again doesn't say much; it says I need to be logged in to chat. If I click on the "log in via StackExchange.com" it says I'm logged in! (Which I am.)

But I'm not. I still can't chat because the particular chat site I'm looking at doesn't think I'm logged in.

**System details:**
I'm using Safari version 7.1.4 on OS X version 10.9.5. I've had this problem across multiple versions of Safari and OS X.

**And OMG, this is Safari-specific**. With another browser (I just tried with Firefox), I have no problem.

**Second thought:**
This might be a cookie problem rather than a Safari-specific problem. I generally let Safari store cookies. There are too many websites that croak if I don't first let them eat a cookie. I do not let Firefox store cookies between sessions. I want both a cookie-full and cookie-free browser, and with multiple browsers available, I can have just that.

**Third thought:**
I just managed to log in to the particular chat session I wanted to use with Safari. It wasn't easy. I managed to log in at https://chat.stackexchange.com, and then I searched for the chat site I wanted where I wanted to say something. This is a beta site, so it's on page six of the list of chat sites. Fun!

**Aside:**
Apparently I made a user feel bullied.

He/she gave what I thought was a very  wrong but accepted answer. I responded that that answer was wrong (which it is, IMO). That user felt compelled to change his/her username to "inactive" because of being bullied. I did not think I attacked the person who gave the wrong answer. To quote exactly, I wrote "this answer is so very wrong" -- and then I gave reasons, and then I gave a counter answer. While I certainly did criticize the answer in question, I did not criticize the person who gave the answer.

Then again, tactfulness is not one of attributes. Given the name change, I felt an apology was necessary. But I couldn't do that because I couldn't log in to chat!

I myself have given wrong answers; my response has generally been to delete them and in retrospect give thanks to the person who pointed out that my answer was wrong. No hard feelings! I have no problem with checking my ego in at the door.

I do have a couple of answers with negative votes that I haven't deleted where I think the downvoters are wrong. No hard feelings! I've gone through the peer review process multiple times at work. No hard feelings! But others apparently don't feel the same way.

Comment: "Welcome to The Stack Exchange Network chat!" covers the login button ಠ_ಠ